# sudo stopped working after a failed dependency update

Tags: package-management, sudo, dependencies

`sudo` stopped working after I have tried to update a dependency from libc6XXXX to libc6YYYY, required by an experimental text editor.

On the first try, it didn't work and `apt-get` suggested I use the `--auto-deconfigure` flag.  From then on, `sudo` stopped working and, because of that, I can't log in to my notebook any more.

All the tips I found are based on the assumption that if `sudo` doesn't work it is due to some problem in the `sudoers` file, but that's not the issue in my case.  It is the broken dependency.

All the tips I found to fix broken dependencies start with `sudo <something>`.

Is there anything that can be done or just reinstalling everything again?  I can access the disk via pendrive boot.  I have already thought about replacing the old libc6 on top of what is broken, but I am afraid of making things worse.  Any help?

Comment: Does `pkexec` work?

Comment: My guess is that you can boot from usb, and then chroot to the hard drive, and try to reinstall/deinstall the problematic packages.  But I am not an expert with chroot...

Comment: @eliah-kagan I could try using `pkexec` if I managed to log in to my notebook.  I imagine that it would not have the desired effect if I ran it in the boot shell made by the pendrive since the execution context would be that of the pendrive and not the installation that is broken, correct?

Comment: @ott-toomet Yes, it looks like a promising idea, I'm not a chroot expert either, so I need to investigate.  I know it can be used for system recovery.  And, now that you mention it, it should have been used in dependency control to avoid just this situation :(

Comment: I don't know enough about Ubuntu Desktop, but in Server I can log into console as `root`.